# PHP For loop issue with Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get this PHP script to paginate the data pulled from the mysql database.

It is going wrong somewhere in the second `for` loop. Instead of pulling the data through it is just returning blank or empty fields.

I need it to display the title, description and content fields from the database, along with the ID.

```
        require_once("../controls/config.php");
        $connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if ($connection->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connection->connect_error);
            exit();
}

        // number of results to show per page
        $per_page = 3;

        // figure out the total pages in the database
        $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM pages");
        $total_results = $result->num_rows;
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                {
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page; 
                }
                else
                {
                        // error - show first set of results
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page; 
                }               
        }
        else
        {
                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page; 
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
                echo "<a href='?page=$i'>$i</a><br>";
        }

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
        {
                // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

                echo $i["id"].' ';
                echo $i["title"].' ';
                echo $i["description"].' ';
                echo $i["content"].' ';
                echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$i["id"].'">Edit</a> ';
                echo '<a href="delete.php?id='.$i["id"].'">Delete</a><br>';

        }

?>
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you use `$i` as an index, how on earth are you trying to access some stuff like `$i["id"]`? :)

Comment: @Jari i've only been working with PHP for a few days, it seemed logical as I am trying to pull data for id, title, description etc, for each matched record of the database. Can you shed any light on what I should be doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate a mysqli result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214816/how-to-iterate-a-mysqli-result-set)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Of course I do. What difference does it make? A question is still a question even when the user does not exist.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It is an autogenerated comment posted by the system when you vote to close as a duplicate. I didn't write that. The system posted it. I only voted to close a question

Comment: @JayBlanchard A better answer by mickmackusa was posted over in the other question. It helps to link them together so that people can find the better answer. I found this question using Google search when I was looking for the other one and I decided to link them together. Age of the question doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to treat $i as an associative array. Though $i is only a integer. Additionally, you do not have an array the contains the results from your mysqli query. You should try:

```
// this will loop through results and assign to $rows array
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}

// this will loop through $rows array and provide each column result
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["title"];
    echo $row["description"];
    echo $row["content"];
}
```

For further information please refer to: https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: This works to pull the data correct but then doesn't fit into the pagination structure. How can I make it do that?

Comment: You could try the following:  `for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
 echo $rows[$i]["id"]; 
    echo $rows[$i]["title"];
    echo $rows[$i]["description"];
    echo $rows[$i]["content"];
}`  This will loop through the $rows array in a different manor.

Comment: Additionally, I would encourage you to review arrays in PHP. It will help alot when parsing results from a mysql query. Check here: [W3 School on PHP arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_arrays.asp)