# How do I iterate over the results in a MySQLi result set?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop, resultset

I want to loop through the result set of the following query:

```
select uid from userbase
```

I am currently employing the following loop, but I can get only the first value.

```
$i = 0;
$output = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select uid from userbase");
while ($row = $output->fetch_array()) {
    $deviceToken = $row[$i];
    echo $deviceToken;
    $i++;
}
```

What might be the problem? Is it `fetch_array()`?

Comment: You are mixing procedural with OOP, pick one and stick to it to create a consistent code base.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: It will be like $row=$output->mysqli_fetch_array()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to define a array and store your data into array inside loop .
Use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` no need for incremented value

```
$deviceToken=array();
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $deviceToken[] = $row['uid'];
}
print_r($deviceToken);
for($i=0;$i<=count($deviceToken);$i++){
echo $deviceToken[$i];
}
```

Comment: If it has no key, why not just use `array_push`?

Comment: I need to print individual devicetokens that are being fetched. What shall I do?

Comment: Use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and you will get all `uid`. and use for loop to get individual devicetokens

Comment: @saty 
Thanks. You should give the condition inside the for loop as '<'. Not '<='. I was actually inserting them to another table and noticed that at the end of every batch of inserts, a blank data is inserted. Nailed it now. 
For the rest, it works like a charm.

Comment: Use `if( isset($deviceToken[$i]) && $deviceToken[$i]!="")` inside for loop to prevent empty value

Comment: @Saty - you missed Ashif's point, which is that you should correct the expression used in your for loop. `$deviceToken[count($deviceToken)]` is not valid - such an element does not exist. To correctly access the array elements, do `$i<count($deviceToken)` instead of `$i<=count($deviceToken)`.

Comment: I definitely do not recommend making repetitive `count()` calls within a loop.  The count should be cached as a variable (once) and the variable used over and over -- but running two loops on the same result set data is nonsense.

Answer (score 6):

You will notice while researching the PHP manual at https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php that `fetch_array()` has the default behavior of generating a result set that contains both indexed and associative keyed elements (`MYSQLI_BOTH`).

You *could* use either `MYSQLI_ASSOC` ...

```
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['uid'];
}
```

or `MYSQLI_NUM`...

```
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

That said, there is actually an easier, more brief, and more efficient way because MySQLi's `query()` can be used as an iterable object. The step of calling `fetch_array()` on every iterated row can be completely omitted. You can write your `$output` into a `foreach()` and away you go (refer to column values by the associative key).

```
foreach ($output as $row) {
    echo $row['uid'];
}
```

I do recommend that you use all "object oriented" syntax rather than procedural or a mix of styles. "Object oriented" syntax is more brief and in my opinion it is easier to read.

Finally, the way that your code is constructed, `$i` starts at `0` and increments with every row. However, your result set (with both styles of keys) will look something like this...

```
[
    0 => [0 => 1, 'uid' => 1],
    1 => [0 => 2, 'uid' => 2],
    2 => [0 => 3, 'uid' => 3]...
]
```

Your first iteration works because `$output[0][0]` (aka `$row[0]`) exists.
Your second iteration doesn't work because `$output[1][1]` (aka `$row[1]`) doesn't exist.
Nor does the third iteration with `$output[2][2]` (aka `$row[2]`) doesn't exist. And so on.
You see, the iteration was truly the part that fouled up your script.