# display multiple results from a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so I am trying to display multiple results from a database when a query is searched, the query is passed from a search box on another page.

I have it displaying one result, but that is all it will display.
I need it to display all the results that are relevant to the search query.

the php code is below

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'scott', 'tiger','courses');
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        die('Database connection failed');
    }
    //$m->set_charset('utf8');
    $search_sql = "
    SELECT title, summary, id
    FROM course
    WHERE title LIKE '%".$_POST['searchBar']."%'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($search_sql) or die($mysqli->error);
    $search_result = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <h3><?= $search_result['title'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= $search_result['summary'] ?></p>
</body>
```

and the code for the search bar

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<Head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form name="search" method="post" action="SearchResultsPage.php">
        <input name="searchBar" type="text" size="40" maxlength="60" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submitsearch" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </body>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: you need to display only one record or perfect search value result?

Comment: You'd have to loop through the resultset. See the example #1 on [the PHP manual page about fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Also, read about "prepared statements".

Comment: Just read the examples on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate a mysqli result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214816/how-to-iterate-a-mysqli-result-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to place it in a while loop to show multiple results, the fetch function you're using will only retrieve one row, if you place it in a loop you can keep fetching until there is nothing to fetch:

```
//$m->set_charset('utf8');
$search_sql = "
SELECT title, summary, id
FROM course
WHERE title LIKE '%".$_POST['searchBar']."%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($search_sql) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <?PHP while($search_result = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <h1><?= $search_result['title'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= $search_result['summary'] ?></p>
    <?PHP } ?>
</body>
```

P.S. your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should read about prepared statements. [More Info on that](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, I'll have a look into prepared statements as well, thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If you have anymore questions about this don't be hesitant to ask, if not, don't forget to accept an answer so it doesn't stay open :) Prepared statements might seem daunting at first but it's not that bad and it makes secures you from SQL injections ^^ good luck on your project!

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over your query results with a while loop. To complete the example I added the necessary data cleaning.

```
<?php

// function to clean post data
function cleanPost(&$value) {

    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $value[$k] = cleanPost($v);             
        }
        return $value;
    }
    else {
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        return trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($value)));
    }
}

// search function
function search() {

    // check if post data is set
    if (isset($_POST['searchBar'])) {

        // make link with db
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'scott', 'tiger','courses');
        if (!$link)         
            return false;
        }

        // clean your post data
        $cleanPostData = cleanPost($_POST);

        // query
        $sql = "SELECT title, summary, id FROM course WHERE title LIKE '%".$cleanPostData['searchBar']."%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        // iterate over results
        if (isset($result) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // here is your data
                echo $row['title'] . "< br/>";
                echo $row['summary'] . "< br/>";
                echo $row['id'] . "< br/>";
            }
        }       
    }
}

// call search function
search();

?>
```

Comment: also you're mixing mysql and mysqli functions, that will give problems.