# Query dont want to show all related post from table

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to retrive all rows related to the specific category(continent table) but it only shows one and not all.

```
<?php

$townid = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM towns INNER JOIN continents ON towns.catid = continents.id WHERE continents.id = '$townid'";

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $query));

// The category/Continent
echo '<h1>';
echo $row['catname'];
echo '</h1>';


//The post name/Town name
echo $row['title'];

?>
```

Comment: You only called `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` once, so you only show one row. Call it in a loop.

Comment: Any tutorial on showing data from SQL tables should show that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate a mysqli result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214816/how-to-iterate-a-mysqli-result-set)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in a loop.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$first = true;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($first) { // Only show the category header once.
        // The category/Continent
        echo '<h1>';
        echo $row['catname'];
        echo '</h1>';
        $first = false;
    }   

    //The post name/Town name
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<?php
    $townid = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM towns INNER JOIN continents ON towns.catid = continents.id WHERE continents.id = '$townid'";

    $rows = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($link, $query), MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // The category/Continent
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<h1>';
        echo $row['catname'];
        echo '</h1>';

        //The post name/Town name
        echo $row['title'];
     }

 ?>
```

On another note, its better to parameterised your query since you are getting the `$townid` from a GET params.
This is how to do it in PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php